# Use Clang to convert C++ to C code

Tags: c++, c, clang, llvm, frontend

I know that `llvm` can be used to convert c++ into c code.  I was wondering if `clang` could do the same thing (seeing as `clang` was derived from `llvm`).

So can I use `clang` to convert c++ code into c code?

If you want to know why I want to do this here is my scenario:

PIC, which is a micro controller manufacturer, does not make c++ compilers, but does make c compilers for most of their products.  I want to write in c++ and then as part of my build process, convert the c++ code into a temporary c file, which is then fed into the PIC compiler, and viola I have written c++ code for a PIC micro.

Comment: "I know that llvm can be used to convert c++ into c code" - How that? LLVM is a compiler infrastructure library. It does not even know C or C++. Maybe you better read the documentation what LLVM and clang actually are.

Comment: @Olaf http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/FAQ.html#translatecxx

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But I'd not call that C code; it is more like Assembler with C syntax (read the text). You definitively don't want such code in your project (and every senior will refuse such code anyway).

Comment: @Olaf That is actually all I need.....Here is why I need it:  PIC (a micro controller brand) does not make `c++` compilers for any of its micros (except the really fancy ones), but it does make c compilers.....So I wanted to use a converter to generate temporary which would get fed into the PIC compiler.....I will update the question to reflect this

Comment: If that is for PIC32: use gcc (IIRC they already provide gcc for that). For PIC16: You also can use gcc. However, for both variants: Using C++ coding style for PIC16 will result in terrible code. Not only at the source level, but - worse - at the machine level. These MCUs are not really designed to support C, less C++ with its OOP features. You really either should change to something better suited like MSP430 or ARMv6M/7M or you write true C code. Note the converted C code will very likely also not be well optimisable, the Microchip compiler is know to be really bad at this.

Comment: @Olaf You can use gcc for PIC?  (Do you know if you can use it for PIC8s?)

Comment: What is PIC8? It might well be sdcc, not gcc. Long time ago I used that rubbish; they are just ancient and should be locked up in a museum now. Anyway, you missed the point: **don't** write your code in C++ - be it with a direct compiler or - worse - through a C intermediate stage! You would not use Python or Java on that box either.

Comment: @Olaf http://www.microchip.com/design-centers/8-bit  They technically aren't called PIC8s they are just "8 bit PICS"

Comment: They are called PIC16/18. That's what I mean. Forget about the smaller ones, they are really more than obsolete now. Or have you been punished with maintaining some old project and make it "ready for IoT" while still using the old MCU (but with a some 100MHz ARM for communication - for cost efficiency reason)?

Answer (score 7):

Clang can read C++ and emit LLVM IR.  You seem to be aware that LLVM can read IR and emit C (from your own link: http://llvm.org/releases/3.1/docs/FAQ.html#translatecxx).  So Clang cannot directly emit C, but it can emit LLVM IR which you then turn around and convert to C.  Two steps, and Clang is one of them.

Comment: Note that the C backend functionality was [removed](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project?view=revision&revision=153307) about four years ago. You’ll need to go back in time quite a way to use it. Proceed with appropriate caution.

Comment: @BenjaminBarenblat: Wow that sucks.  Well, I just found (but haven't tested) this: https://github.com/draperlaboratory/llvm-cbe

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to convert C++ to C in two steps: first using [Emscripten](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten) to compile C++ to WebAssembly, and then using [wasm2c](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt/tree/main/wasm2c) to convert the generated WebAssembly modules to C. Emscripten uses Clang to compile C++ to WebAssembly, so it could probably be used to generate C source code in this way.

Since Clang compiles C++ to LLVM, it could also be converted to C using an LLVM decompiler such as [retdec](https://github.com/avast/retdec).