# Customize Clang to convert C++ code to C

Tags: c++, c, clang

Here is my scenario:
I,m working on an embedded linux system and getting a shared library written in C++. It works well except that libstdc++ is required, which means an extra 1M memory is occupied. I want to convert the shared library to C so that 1M memory will be saved.

I know how to convert C++ code to C by hand but it will be really boring. So I searched for solution and getting a similar question: [Use Clang to convert C++ to C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082302/use-clang-to-convert-c-to-c-code). However the generated code is not readable. I want to get maintainable C source code to obsolete the original C++ code.

I'm a newbie at Clang. I have learnt that [Clang can be used to build a tool that processes code](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html). My question is:

1. Is it possible using Clang to achieve my goal?
2. If it is possible, how can I do that? To be more specific, how can I use Clang to remove code blocks wrapped by macro as the first step?

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages. Translating between two languages is not easy and not easy at all to automate. Did you ever try to get something readable out of googletranslate?

Comment: Did you first tried 1. compiling with `-Os` 2. rewritting the C++ code to get rid of as many templates as possible (here is of course space/speed tradeoff) 3. statically link everything ? If not, try that first, converting code to C automatically will not work.

Comment: Actually, you don't need `libstdc++` just because it is C++. You can link your C++ program with `gcc` instead of `g++` and not link `libstdc++`. You'll have to remove all references to `std`, exceptions, RTTI and the like, but you are already willing to to that...

Comment: @Paladin I will try it out, thanks very much.

Comment: I am not at all sure that removing templates win space (it is likely the opposite). For example, standard containers implementation are very well written and tuned.

Comment: @rodrigo hmm, seems a reasonable solution, thanks very much:)

Comment: @Jishu I would just like to point out, that getting completely rid of all std, exceptions, RTTI and ... will require so massive rewrite that you would probably be better of starting all over in C in the first place

Comment: @Paladin: That is a bold statement to make without knowing the original source code. There are a lot of C++ code out there that does not use `std` or exceptions. I've even seen OS kernels written in C++!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *practice* converting (semi-automatically) genuine C++ code to maintainable C code is **not realistic**.

> I want to get maintainable C source code to obsolete the original C++ code.

You certainly won't get maintainable and readable and portable C code (for instance, as soon as standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) are used in C++; their template expansion is *not* readable, and probably not portable to something with different word size, alignment, endianness ...). You could transform [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) IR to some unportable and unreadable subset of C.

> It works well except that libstdc++ is required, which means an extra 1M memory is occupied

Perhaps you could try linking (everything) *statically*; maybe only a part of `libstdc++` is used in your particular application.

BTW, you could get GIMPLE from GCC, and convert that GIMPLE to *unreadable* C code (perhaps by customizing GCC with a plugin or a [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension).

You might also try to compile *and link* with link time optimization, e.g. with `-flto -Os` (with recent GCC or Clang).

Don't forget that development efforts also has some costs. Is it worth spending a whole year of work (or more) for a team of a few developers to win a few hundred kilobytes? In most cases upgrading the hardware to something with slightly more memory would cost a lot less. YMMV

Comment: FWIW, there seems to be `-fdump-tree-gimple` which is supposed to print gimple as C code.

Comment: Not exactly C, but close to it.

Comment: Thanks very much for saving my time :)